# How the country code with the ip address?

Tags: ios, ip-address, country-codes

I would like to know the country code with the ip address.

And without using gps.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried `NSLocale` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `NSLocale` is good option to get country code and name rather then IP so try it like below code:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
NSLog(@"%@ %@",countryName, countryCode);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: yes, but it is changed by changing settings in the regional.

Comment: Then this Free Database may be help you : http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Answer (score 0):

You can download IP to country database from http://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country

To extract country from IP range don't forget to calculate IP number:

```
public Long getIpNumber(String ip) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ip))
        return null;

    String[] ipArray = ip.split("\\.");

    long result = 0;
    long ipLong = 0;

    for (int x = 3; x >= 0; x--) {
        ipLong = Long.parseLong(ipArray[3 - x]);
        result |= ipLong << (x << 3);
    }

    return result;
}
```